# Pulling data to modal using angularjs and mqql

Tags: angularjs

I need to pull data to uiModal using Angularjs and mssql, how can I do it?
modal popup opens but I can't pull data into it
how can i retrieve data from database
Under normal conditions, data comes in when the button is clicked, but I can't get it without the button.

```js
function modalServiceCtrl($scope, $uibModal) {
  
    $scope.open = function () {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'Modules/IK/personneldetail.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
        });
    };
};

function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
    $scope.getEmployee(personnel)
    $scope.Name = personnel.Name;
    $scope.LastName = personnel.LastName;
    $scope.TC = personnel.TC;
    
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    };
};
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h3 class="m-t-none m-b">Personel Kartı</h3> 
            <form >
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-6">TC:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <label class="control-label" ng-model="TC"></label>
                    </div>
                             </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your controller.

```
function ComponentCtrl($scope, $uibModal) {
  $scope.open = function () {
    // make the request to get your data like:
    $http.get(url, {params: params}).then(function(res) {
      // here you can check for any condition and open modal
      $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'Modules/IK/personneldetail.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        resolve: {
          // the data object will be passed to the modal
          data: function () {
            // the content of res will be accesible from the modal controller
            return res;
          }
        }
      }).result.then(function(reason) {
        // handle on close
      }).catch(function(reason) {
        // handle on dismiss
      });
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    })
  };
};
```

Now from the modal controller

```
function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
  $scope.getEmployee(personnel)
  $scope.Name = personnel.Name;
  $scope.LastName = personnel.LastName;
  $scope.TC = personnel.TC;

  // do something with your data
  // data is what you returned from the resolve in the modal config
  $scope.myData = $uibModalInstance.data;

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close();
  };
};
```